# Openshift mySQL character_set_server utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, openshift, utf8mb4

I have a Spring web application talking to a mySQL database through hibernate. I am trying to set up utf8mb4 as the database character encoding. I have performed the following steps:

1. Setup my database using

   ```
   SET NAMES utf8mb4; 
   ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
   ```
2. Change hibernate url to

   ```
    hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:myport/mydb?character_set_server=utf8mb4
   ```
3. Add `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` to database connection initial SQLs on my Spring application configuration
4. Added `character_set_server=utf8mb4` at my.cnf

I managed to get my application working properly with a local database. Also what I found is that step 2 is not necessary and without step 4 my setup was not working locally.
In Openshift however I have not found a way to perform step 4. Is there any other solution to this problem? I have tried to change `character_set_server` through phpMyAdmin variables but this is not working either.

Comment: Look for Spring and Hibernate in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have not managed to find any solution to my problem regarding utf8mb4

Comment: What symptoms do you have?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for several common problems, plus solutions.

Comment: Well my problem is that on mySQL database on Openshift cloud all emojis are stored as ??. The issue is that character_set_server is set to latin rather than utf8mb4. I know that in order to fix this I need to modify my.cnf but this is not possible on the Openshift cloud. So I am looking for any other solution that I can use on Openshift

Comment: Search for "question marks" in [_this_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I read the section for the question marks but I did not find any solution I could use in my case

Answer (score 0):

There's another MySQL cartridge which can be configured to use utf8mb4. Just backup the data from your database. Remove your MySQL cartridge and add this one:

https://github.com/amgohan/openshift-origin-cartridge-mysql-utf8mb4

And finally restore the backup into your new database.